# How to Add captcha in COD method in Checkout page in magento 1.x &2.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, payment-methods

How to add captcha in payment method..appreciate for reply.
[image]

Comment: If you can customize https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Comment: I need to enable the captcha on all the payment methods. Do you find any solution for this?